# Autostart a youtube video from Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, autoplay, embedded-video

I am trying to automatically start a youtube video when it loads and when it finishes I want it to alert that it's done.

This is my HTML/JS

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
        }
    }

</script>
```

The part that alerts when the video is done is working but the auto-player doesn't. I HAVE TRIED TO PUT THE `?AUTOPLAY=1` TAG AFTER THE VIDEO URL BUT THAT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK EITHER!

I have seen all the variations to this question and tried all the anwsers but none of them work.

Does anyone have any idea on what I should try next?

Comment: Is there any chance the browser is disabling autoplay if the video has sound? I think some of them are doing this now.

Comment: @cat Could be, god knows why but it seems to be working just fine in firefox but doesn't work in Chrome or Opera

Comment: If so, you may not be able to force the browser to behave as you want. (If Chrome is willing to autoplay silent videos, of course you could disable sound and have the user click to enable it, but in that case, they could have just clicked to play the video.)

Comment: If that's the issue, you may want to see the "Best practices for web developers" section here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Thank you @cat, you have solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [cat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8223070/cat) my problem is solved!

All I had to do is go to `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` and select "No user gesture is required" in the dropdown menu under the "Autoplay policy" and then relaunch chrome.

Answer (score 0):

player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          autoplay: 1,
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }

Comment: I have tried autoplay and still not working in chrome